# C++ return null pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code below and I think there is something that I don't understand.
`d_header` is a pointer of type `WaterHeater` and a variable of the class `house`. 
Line 2 creates a pointer that points to a `d_heater` object. Since both are pointing to the same object, if either `obj` or `d_header` is changed, the change will be reflected in the other. Line 3 assigns `nullptr` to `d_header` and line 4 returns `obj`. First question: Isn't `obj` also pointing to null, since both object were pointing to the same object? So what is the deal of returning a Null pointer? Second question: is `nullptr` in this case would be the same as `delete`?  
Thanks for your time.

```
WaterHeater* house::removeWaterHeater(){ //Line 1
    WaterHeater *obj = d_heater;         //Line 2
    d_heater = nullptr;                  //Line 3
    return obj;                          //Line 4
}
```

Comment: Not a full answer so I'm just going to put it into a comment - `nullptr` doesn't mean you're pointing to null, but rather that it value is a null pointer (in other words an invalid pointer or empty pointer - a pointer to nowhere in some sense). This should give a glance at an answer to your first question. A glance to your second: no.

Comment: You said it's not pointing to null but an empty pointer, isn't that the same thing?

Comment: `void *x = NULL; int *y = &x;` `y` points to `NULL`, but `y` is not a `null` pointer.

Comment: this makes more sens thank you!!

Comment: That little example looks like it won't compile.

Comment: @celticmenstrel I think that's just a code snipit. You'd need `class house` and `class WaterHeater` to make it compile. Which aren't really relevant to the problem. If you want to see a more generalized example of the problem that *will* compile you can look at [the live example](http://ideone.com/I8CTba) linked in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31216788/2642059).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since both are pointing to the same object, if either `obj` or `d_header` is changed, the change will be reflected in the other.

That is incorrect. If the contents of what they point to is changed, that change can be seen through either pointer but if one of them is changed so that it points to something different, the other will still point to the previous object.

Simple example:

```
int i = 10;
int j = 20;

int* ptr1 = &i;
int* ptr2 = ptr1;
```

At this point, both the pointers point to the same object, `i`. Value of `i` can be changed by:

1. Directly by assigning a value to `i`.

   ```
    i = 15;
   ```
2. Indirectly by assigning a value to where `ptr1` points to.

   ```
    *ptr1 = 15;
   ```
3. Indirectly by assigning a value to where `ptr2` points to.

   ```
    *ptr2 = 15;
   ```

However, you can change where `ptr1` points to by using:

```
ptr1 = &j;
```

Now, `ptr1` points to `j` but `ptr2` still points to `i`.

Any changes made to `i` will be visible through `ptr2` but not `ptr1`.
Any changes made to `j` will be visible through `ptr1` but not `ptr2`.

> Isn't `obj` also pointing to null, since both object were pointing to the same object?

The answer should be clear now. `obj` continues to point to what `d_header` used to point to. It is not NULL.

> So what is the deal of returning a Null pointer?

The function does not necessarily return a NULL pointer. The function returns whatever `d_header` used to point to before it was changed to be `nullptr`. It could be a NULL pointer if `d_header` used to be NULL before the call to the function.

> is `nullptr` in this case would be the same as `delete`?

No, it is not. There are two different operations. Assigning a pointer to `nullptr` does not automatically mean that `delete` gets called on the pointer. If you need to deallocate memory that a pointer points to, you'll have to call to call `delete` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

## Q: "Isn't obj also pointing to null, since both object were pointing to the same object?"

No, both `obj` and `d_heater` contain addresses in memory. Changing one does not change the other. This is easy to see if you think about non-pointer variables:

```
int foo = 13;
int bar = foo;
foo = 42;
```

Obviously we know that `bar` still holds `13`, and in the same way `obj` still holds the original address.

If you *want* `obj` to keep the same value as `d_heater` you can make it a reference, then `obj` and `d_heater` are the same *variable* they don't simply share the same *value*. We can see this again looking at non-pointer variables, but this time let's make `bar` a reference:

```
int foo = 13;
int& bar = foo;
foo = 42;
```

Now both `foo` and `bar` will equal 42. If you want to accomplish the same thing with `obj` make it a pointer reference:

```
WaterHeater*& obj = d_heater;
```

You can see a more detailed example here: http://ideone.com/I8CTba

## Q. "Is `nullptr` in this case would be the same as `delete`?"

No, again `d_heater` is only an *address*. If you assign a new value to `d_heater` it is simply referencing a different point in memory. If by reassigning `d_heater` you lose the address of dynamically allocated memory that's very bad, it's known as a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). To prevent leaking you must always release dynamically allocated memory before losing the last address to your dynamically allocated memory (call `delete` for memory allocated with `new`.)

That said, use of dynamic memory allocation is best left to the standard libraries, unless you really know what you're doing. So I'd strongly recommend you look at using [auto-pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). In C++11 those are [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: thanks but your examples are not quite relevant . `d_heater` is also a pointer not a simple integer.

Comment: @Bobby Those are just to help you understand the concept. Although C++ treats pointers differently than other primitives, at it's core any pointer is just an integer. For me it is helpful to think about pointers like simple integers in certain situations, I was hoping this would be helpful to you as well. Either way I'd certainly look at the example I typed up: http://ideone.com/I8CTba

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the ideas of two pointers *pointing to the same object* and two pointers *being the same object*. When you write:

```
WaterHeater *obj = d_heater;
d_heater = nullptr;
```

You're assigning the value of `d_heater` to obj, but they're still separate variables. It's just like writing:

```
int x = 7;
int y = x;
x = 8;
```

`y` is still 7 of course because while `x` and `y` have the same value they are not the same object.

So `d_heater` and `obj` are two, distinct entities that happen to have the same the value, and assignments made to one will not be reflected in the other. However, `*d_heater` and `*obj` *are the same object*, and if we assign to one of them, it will be reflected in the other. This is where you're getting confused.

To answer your second question, `nullptr` is never the same as `delete`. `delete` doesn't change a pointer's value: it frees/deconstructs the object that the pointer *points to*. Assigning `nullptr` or `NULL` to a pointer doesn't affect the object it points: it just reassigns the pointer not to point to an object.

Answer (score 0):

obj isn't point to `null`. it just point, as you mentioned, to a `null` pointer (`d_header`).
And it doesn't as the same as `delete`, you have just made it point to nothing(like empty).

Answer (score 0):

`nullptr` is not pointing to the `NULL` pointer. Check [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) for reference.

If you are doing this:

```
WaterHeater* house::removeWaterHeater(){ //Line 1
    WaterHeater *obj = d_heater;         //Line 2
    d_heater = NULL;                     //Line 3
    return obj;                          //Line 4
}
```

Now, `obj` is also pointing to a `NULL`.
And `nullptr` does not mean `delete`.